# jquery show/hide with text and triangle - triangle moves, but text disappears

Tags: jquery, show-hide

Here is Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zuhloobie/1m0wu7wc/6/

I want to click on a topic name that reveals information below it. That topic has a down triangle next to it. When I click the topic name, the name should stay but the triangle becomes an up triangle. My problem is getting the topic name to stay. Just the triangle stays.

I know that the name doesn't stay because I'm replacing `$(showHide)` with the triangles. But, I've tried html(), text(), append() and prepend() to try and grab the text within the class `dept` and stick it before the triangles but I can't get it to work. Prepend sort of works, but it is pulling both topic names and sticking them together since they have the same class name of `dept` and that has to be used multiple times throughout the page. So I want to grab only the instance of `dept` where I'm clicking and ignore the other `dept` classes. Hope I'm explaining this well enough.

I don't have full control over the code as this is from code I cannot access. I can only control/change classes `dept` and `showHideTri`. Everything else, I'm stuck with.

How can I tweak my code to make the topic name stay while the triangles move? I'm fairly new at jquery so this may be super simple? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing entire `expandable` class, but you only need to change the triangle inside `.expandable`.

Change

```
var showHide = this;
```

to

```
var showHide = $(this).find(".showHideTri");
```

[**Updated fiddle is here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/1m0wu7wc/7/)

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the help and quick response. The next thing I'd like to happen is have one topic close while you open another topic - basically an accordion. I'll do some research and come back to SO if I get stuck. Thanks again :)